# ORA-40478- output value too large (maximum: 4000) even when returning clob

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Even when returning CLOB the same error is raised.
I have increased the string size in database to extended, but still the error exists.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(
                   'assmCode' VALUE part_group.assm_code,
                   'slotCode' VALUE part_group.slot_code,
                   'partGroupCode' VALUE part_group.part_group_code,
                   'partGroupName' VALUE part_group.part_group_name,
                   'invClassCode' VALUE part_group.inv_class_code,
                   'effectivity' VALUE part_group.effectivity,
                   'quantity' VALUE part_group.quantity,
                   'condition' VALUE part_group.condition,
                   'isReqSpecPart' VALUE DECODE(part_group.is_req_spec_part,'1','true','false'),
                   'alternates' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                                             JSON_OBJECT(
                                                   'interChgOrd' VALUE pg_part.inter_chg_ord,
                                                   'effectivity' VALUE pg_part.effectivity,
                                                   'isStandard' VALUE DECODE(pg_part.is_standard,'1','true','false'),
                                                   'isConditional' VALUE DECODE(pg_part.is_conditional,'1','true','false'),
                                                   'isApproved' VALUE DECODE( pg_part.rowstate , 'Approved' , 'true','false'),
                                                   'part' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(
                                                                         'oemPartNo' VALUE part.oem_part_no,
                                                                         'manufacturerCode' VALUE part.manufacturer_code,
                                                                         'partName' VALUE part.part_name,
                                                                         'isPmaPart' VALUE DECODE(part.is_pma_part,'1','true','false')
                                                                      )RETURNING CLOB) FROM opr_publish_part part
                                                                           WHERE part.opr_publish_part_id = pg_part.opr_publish_part_id)
                                             )RETURNING CLOB)FROM opr_publish_pg_part_tab pg_part
                                               WHERE publish_part_group_id = part_group.publish_part_group_id AND pg_part.rowstate!='Unassigned'))RETURNING CLOB)
   FROM opr_publish_part_group_tab part_group
   WHERE publish_part_group_id = 123123;
```

The actual issue resides in the select statement of the JSON key 'part', since it returns more than 4000 bytes of data.

I have tried few ways to fix this issue but same error is raised.
1) Changing database string size to extend.
2) Returning VARCHAR2(32000).

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you using?

Comment: The oracle version that im using is 12c.

Comment: Have you bounced the database since setting the max string size?

Comment: Yes, I did shutdown and restart the database after the upgrade.

Comment: Consider using APEX_JSON package. It can write json to CLOB or htp.p directly.